# qmake, build producing a custom library name

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I have a .pro file named `XYZ.pro`. Here is it.

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = XYZ
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += plugin

DESTDIR = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/generic

SOURCES += cc.cpp

HEADERS += cc.h
DISTFILES += XYZ.json
```

I want the build to product a library `ABC.o`.

How do I do this?

Comment: To get ABC.o library try to change TARGET to ABC,TARGET_EXT to o.

Comment: That did it...  Durp. I initially did that, but I didn't realize I had to run qmake after every change to the .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

TARGET = ABC

And make sure qmake is re-run after the change.